# Always return NullPointerException in array list when mocking in controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, junit, mockito

I try to make simple unit test using JUnit and Mockito in the controller. I mocked the service because it will be called by the controller.
Here is the code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MsCustomerControllerTest {
    
    @Mock
    MsCustomerService customerServiceMock;

    
    @InjectMocks
    MsCustomerController customerController;
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
    

    
    @Test
    public void findAllCustomerTest() {
        
        List<MsCustomer> listCustomer = new ArrayList<MsCustomer>();
        listCustomer.add(new MsCustomer(1, "Rosa", "Titian Indah", LocalDateTime.now()));
        listCustomer.add(new MsCustomer(2, "Rosa2", "Titian Indah2", LocalDateTime.now()));
        when(customerServiceMock.findAllCustomer()).thenReturn(listCustomer);
        
        ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity(listCustomer, HttpStatus.OK);
        
        
        assertEquals(response, customerController.findAllCustomer());
    }

}
```

note: the customerController also return response entity, so assert with response entity too.

Here is the result

[image]

I have tried other method and it also give me the NullPointerException.

Comment: could you please share your MsCustomerController code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an init method and annotate it with `@BeforeEach`.
Then inside the method add `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` which initializes fields annotated with Mockito annotations.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
class MsCustomerControllerTest {
    
    @Mock
    MsCustomerService customerServiceMock;

    
    @InjectMocks
    MsCustomerController customerController;

    @BeforeEach
    void initMock() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
    
    @Test
    void test() {
        fail("Not yet implemented");
    }
    

    
    @Test
    public void findAllCustomerTest() {
        
        List<MsCustomer> listCustomer = new ArrayList<MsCustomer>();
        listCustomer.add(new MsCustomer(1, "Rosa", "Titian Indah", LocalDateTime.now()));
        listCustomer.add(new MsCustomer(2, "Rosa2", "Titian Indah2", LocalDateTime.now()));
        when(customerServiceMock.findAllCustomer()).thenReturn(listCustomer);
        
        ResponseEntity response = new ResponseEntity(listCustomer, HttpStatus.OK);
        
        
        assertEquals(response, customerController.findAllCustomer());
    }

}
```